# How to use a CAN BUS USB Connector

Tags: automotive, can, ftdi

I have one of those "cheap" [ODB2 CAN bus cables](https://www.amazon.de/AutoDia-CarPort-Software-Diagnose-Interface/dp/B00BUPQMG0) to access the CAN bus of my car with a software. I would now like to log the CAN bus. I would like to develop my own software for this. Unfortunately, I lack the information on how to address this connector.

Enclosed I have collected some information that might be a little informative.

- PIC18F66K80 MCU
- TJA1040 CAN BUS transceiver
- FT232R FTDI

The CAN bus is routed to the TJA, where it is connected to the MCU via a serial connection, and the MCU is connected to the USB via FTDI. I have already been able to open a serial connection using Putty, but no data is displayed.

My question now: Where exactly should I start to read data from the CAN bus with this connector?

[image]

Comment: Opening a comm port does not confirm that it was the right port, or that the settings were correct. Are you sure you got these right? What are you expecting to see?

Comment: Off-topic, that's a pretty nasty oscillator layout there. What else on this little board had higher layout priorities... are they actively looking to cause EMC problems or something...

Comment: Even if you can open the correct port and choose the correct baud rate, there is no way you can know what to send to make the PIC MCU to do something. Unless, you know from some document or have a program which you can reverse-engineer. Or find a program someone has already reverse-engineered.

Comment: @Lundin considering you could have built the same with a single microcontroller that does CAN and USB … I don't think whoever layouted this board had any significant design experience. This looks like a cheap copy of an existing device that some pour soul had to relayout to fit a specific form factor.

Comment: [K509 with schematic](https://www.blafusel.de/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=3303&start=15)

Comment: First of all, thank you guys! @StainlessSteelRat thats awesome! Thanks! To the Rest, how hard would it be to implement his own firmware onto the PIC MCU? I've never used this kind of MCU before and only hav experience with Arduino etc.